# Developer's control panel and web services - keep in 1 project or separate them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, api

Do you keep the developer's control panel and the application's web service, in 1 project? or do you separate them into 2 different projects?

(Developer's control panel, is used to setup the web service API, check logs, read document specification, and details about each web service)

When you host the solution you would do something like this..

```
developer.domain.com <-- developer's control panel

api.domain.com <--- web service api

or 

api.domain.com <-- both developer's control pnel and web service api
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend separating the two domains (e.g. into "developers.domain.com" for the control panel / documentation and "api.domain.com" for the API itself). This is important for cross-site-scripting safety.

If both are on "api.domain.com", the following can happen:

- Suppose you are logged into the control panel, and thus have a cookie to api.domain.com
- You now visit a completely different site, evildomain.com, which has some malicious Flash or Silverlight content that appears to do something innocent (e.g. a game, movie, etc)
- The malicious Flash or Silverlight content tries to make a call to api.domain.com to steal or modify your personal information (it makes the call to a control panel page, NOT to the API itself!)
- The malicious call would automatically get the login cookie attached to it by the browser, and so will look like a legitimate call to the control panel site
- The api.domain.com will have to be cross-domain-enabled (with the crossdomain.xml file) to enable legitimate API calls from Flash/Silverlight clients, and so the malicious call will go through as well, and thus the control panel site will be compromised!

There are ways to avoid the attack above while still keeping the API and the control panel on the same domain, but the easiest way to avoid it is to separate the domains.

Comment: hmm im confused, how does the fake site deal the user's cookie? the cookie is on the user's computer! also the api and the control panel does not have the same user credentials. ie developer Control panel username and password and API username and password are two completely different credentials. No session is created for the API as well, only session is created when the using the web application/developer control panel.

Comment: The evil site serves up a Flash (or Silverlight) application, which runs in the user's browser, which means it can make requests with the user's cookies. For a more detailed description, see http://scorbs.com/2008/04/22/silverlight-http-networking-stack-part-3-configuring-a-cross-domain-policy-file/ - the blog post is Silverlight-specific but the same logic applies to Flash as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to separate this when:

- There is no technical reason to keep them separate;
- You have authentication setup correctly so that you're sure only the developers can access this;
- The developer tools are actually tied specifically to `api.domain.com`.

If you e.g. had multiple applications (`api1`, `api2`, `api3`, etc) and the developer site actually spans these different applications, then, yes keep them separate.

If the above reasons don't apply, go what you feel fits best.

Comment: I keep them separate because im not sure if there will be many apps or web services later on, (I go with the safest route and this is the safest).

Comment: If you design your developer tools such that you will be able to span multiple sites later on, then yes, a separate domain is the way to go.